# How to disable all other things except current windows form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i have developed windows application.
started my application at startup window by copying exe to startup folder.
Application is full screen window.
so i have disable taskbar,taskmanager etc.
have some trouble to disable windows explorer.
what should i do to disable window explorer.
means user cant do anything like open my computer except current application.

**In short 
User will only use my application..no use of computer..On exit button in my winform write code for machine shut down**

Comment: Do you have any example code for what you have tried?

Comment: Please try the following link: http://tinyurl.com/amxp2y3

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/435275/can-you-disable-windows-explorer-from-starting-with-windows

Comment: user cant do anything like open my computer except current application....User will only use my application..no use of computer..On exit button in my winform write code for machine shut down.

Comment: Are you supplying the hardware to your customers, like in a retail or kiosk environment? If so, consider installing [Windows embedded](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/retail.aspx) on the hardware; this allows your apps to take the place of Windows Explorer et al.

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure Windows as a kiosk.

http://teamtutorials.com/windows-tutorials/configuring-your-own-kiosk-machine

http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/how-to-setup-windows-vista-and-7-as-a-kiosk/

Comment: have to make Application console display.

Answer (score 1):

Set form `topmost` to true for displaying the form as a [topmost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost.aspx) form.Topmost forms are always displayed at the highest point in the z-order of the windows on the desktop.

Comment: Currently, I'm working on a windows form. For some reasones, I need that whenever I'll execute my windows form, all other things, like start menu, task manager,task bar should be disabled.
Means, user shouldn't be able to use Start menu button, ALT+TAB, Browser, etc...
My windows form will be running full screen.

Is there any code available for this purpose in C# .Net ?

Comment: in short User will only use my application..no use of computer..On exit button in my winform write code for machine shut down

Comment: You can kill explorer progress like this: `var explorers = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer");
foreach (var thisExplorer in explorers)
{
    thisExplorer.Kill();
}`

Comment: Nothing stops Explorer from being relaunched, though. And killing Explorer doesn't stop Ctrl+Alt+Del from working. The correct solution is to use Group Policy to lock down the machine. This has nothing to do with programming, and any effort to implement it programmatically is doomed to fail.

Comment: @ Cody Gray:Taskmanager can be disable from Registry.like this:http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/216453/How-to-Disable-CTRLplusALTplusDEL-Key

Comment: Doesn't work on my machine. Ctrl+Alt+Del is the secure attention sequence, it invokes the secure desktop, not Task Manager. Depends on configuration. And once you have to reconfigure the machine, you might as well do it the right way and use Group Policy.